# Installing VM via the exec resource in puppet

Tags: puppet, centos7, kvm

I'm trying to use `exec` resource in puppet 5 to install a CentOS virtual machine (VM). My manifest is as follows:

```
exec {'centOS-vm':
  cwd => '/root',
  command => '/usr/bin/virt-install --name=centOS --ram=1024 --vcpus=1 --os-
  variant=rhel7 --nographics --disk path=/tmp/centOS-VM.img,size=4 --extra-
  args "console=ttyS0" --location=/tmp/iso-images-VM/CentOS-7-x86_64-
  Minimal-1708.iso',
  logoutput =>true,
}
```

While the above initiates the `KVM` for CentOS installation, there are certain inputs that need to be provided by the user during the installation. Such as choosing the type of installation, etc..

Can this be achieved? Because, the puppet doesn't provide a active terminal for user inputs or for issuing arguments.

Comment: Have you tried any of the modules from the Forge?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the above using a kickstart file. The utility, [Kickstart configurator](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/ch-redhat-config-kickstart.html) can be made use off to create a error free kickstarter file, which can then be injected into the `visrh-install` as given below:

```
/usr/bin/virt-install --name=centOS --ram=1024 --vcpus=1 --os-variant=rhel7 
--nographics --disk path=/tmp/centOS-VM.img,size=4 --extra-
args="console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200" --location=/tmp/iso-images-
VM/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1708.iso --initrd-inject=/root/ks.cfg --extra-
args "ks=file:/ks.cfg console=ttyS0"
```

Here, `ks.cfg` is the kickstart configuration file.